# Obtaining an object state

Tags: java, hibernate

Does hibernate provide a method that returns an object's state (transient, persistent, detached)?

Comment: imho you cannot by design, however +1 since this is an interesting problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [Javadoc Hibernate Session](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) and check the methods

- contains - Check if this instance is associated with this Session.
- getIdentifier - Return the identifier value of the given entity as associated with this session. Beware of the Exception that is thrown if the Entity is not associated, each Exception should be considered fatal and the Session should not be used after it
- get - Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, or null if there is no such persistent instance.

i would use 'get' and furthermore check for changed values, after that its just an "saveOrUpdate" to persist or update (and re-attach) the actual object

Answer (score 3):

[Session.contains](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) tells you if an object is associated with the session. If it has no identifier, it's transient, if it has an identifier and associated with the session, persistent. Identifier but not associated with a session, detached.

If that doesn't help, consider rephrasing your question with more context, that is, why do you need to know the state of an object in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with a usage of `session.contains(obj)` to reveal hibernate object state. An object formerly persisted/loaded would be assumed as TRANSIENT after a simple call of `session.clear()` - if you got no primary key but a composite one you have no idea in which state it is ...

A correct approach can be found inside Hibernate 3: [org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.10.Final/org/hibernate/engine/ForeignKeys.java#ForeignKeys.isTransient%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Boolean,org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor%29)